# How to fix an error on installing packages like lodash and stong-docs in React?

Tags: node.js, typescript, lodash

I got a lot of errors installing packages in my React project. I got a lot of errors related to lodash and strong-docs.

```
node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2448:43 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2448          * **Note:** This method mutates `object`.
                                               ~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2456:30 - error TS1005: ';' expected.

2456          * @returns Returns `object`.
                                  ~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/lodash/common/object.d.ts:2581:1 - error TS1160: Unterminated template literal.

2581

Found 58 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! strong-docs@4.2.0 build: tsc -p tsconfig.json --outdir lib
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the strong-docs@4.2.0 build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Gerald\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2023-11-06T08_01_31_965Z-debug.log
error Command failed with exit code 2.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
```

Comment: I think it's an issue with your lodash or strong-docs types. Are the versions for your type libs up to date? Sharing the command you ran and your `package.json` would be helpful.